# NSManagedObject description in Swift

Tags: core-data, swift

Something weird is going on with `NSManagedObject.description()` it prints nothing but a blank line.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
@objc(MyEntity)
class MyEntity: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var title: String

}
```

Then I create an Object and set its title. When I call `println("\(myObject)")` it will print a blank line instead of `<xSomEtHinG : MyEntity>`
(the object es creates and persists ok. `println("\(myObject.title)")` works like expected)

Any ideas?

Comment: Does `MyEntity` also declare a `description` property?  That's usually my problem when `NSLog` (or `println`) of an `NSManagedObject` isn't working as expected.

Comment: I guess. It works fine in objC. I've even tried creating an extension which overrides description. Same blank line...

Comment: I have the same problem, but so far only for classes that derive from NSManagedObject.  Others seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Extension` and override `description` property as you want.

```swift
extension MyEntity {
    override public var description: String {
        return "Title= \(title)"
    }
}
```